# /etc/hosts has no effect in different browsers

Tags: macos, safari, hosts

I want to block some time consuming websites on my macOS. 
Therefore I added some entries in /etc/hosts like

`127.0.0.1 youtube.com`

I reset the DNS Cache with `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`.

`ping youtube.com` seems to work, as the respons comes from 127.0.0.1.

But all my installed Browsers still shows youtube.com. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: You need to clear your browser cache and history and quit, then relaunch. You should also probably include `www.youtube.com` and `youtu.be` in your hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Clearing the browser cashe helped.